# How to add tooltip to ui multi select

Tags: angular-ui, html-select, ui-select2, angularjs-select2, ui-select

I tried adding tooltip to input box in ui-select but its not working.

> input(type='hidden', ui-select2='userSelect2options',
>   data-placeholder='All User', ng-model='selectedUsersForFilter',
>   style='width:100%;
>   margin-left:5px;',ng-readonly='isUserSelectDisabled', tooltip='Please
>   select atleast one User')

Also instead of tooltip i added simple HTML **title** attribute for the above same input tag, initially it was able to set title but **when i'm trying to change or remove that title its not working** for me.

> input(type='hidden', ui-select2='userSelect2options',
>   data-placeholder='All User', ng-model='selectedUsersForFilter',
>   style='width:100%;
>   margin-left:5px;',ng-readonly='isUserSelectDisabled', **title**='Please
>   select atleast one User')

How to add tool tip for input box in ui-select2 ?

Answer (score 1):

you can add title in the template cache, take bootstrap theme for example

```
$templateCache.put("bootstrap/match-multiple.tpl.html","<span class=\"ui-select-match\"><span ng-repeat=\"$item in $select.selected\"><span title='{{$item.caption}}' class=\"ui-select-match-item btn btn-default btn-xs\" tabindex=\"-1\" type=\"button\" ng-disabled=\"$select.disabled\" ng-click=\"$selectMultiple.activeMatchIndex = $index;\" ng-class=\"{\'btn-primary\':$selectMultiple.activeMatchIndex === $index, \'select-locked\':$select.isLocked(this, $index)}\" ui-select-sort=\"$select.selected\"><span class=\"close ui-select-match-close\" ng-hide=\"$select.disabled\" ng-click=\"$selectMultiple.removeChoice($index)\">&nbsp;&times;</span> <span uis-transclude-append=\"\"></span></span></span></span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as you and solved it creating a custom uiSelect directive that extends the original directive, just like this:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .directive('uiSelect', function ($compile) {
    return {
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        var input = angular.element(element.find('input')[0]);

        if (attrs.ttpMsg) {
          input.attr('tooltip', attrs.ttpMsg);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

And in the view:

```
<ui-select ng-model="myModel" ttp-msg="{{myMessage}}">
  <!-- custom stuff -->
</ui-select>
```

Note that I use a custom attribute (ttp-msg) so I don't have to remove the original 'tooltip' attribute from the element, which could lead to tooltip directive duplication (one for the parent and another for the input or child).

I've tried with some other methods but this is the one that actually worked, although I have to note that I'm unsure if the $compile function puts more overhead on the directive or controllers.

In your sample, I am guessing that you are adding the attributes to the input but you also need to tell angular that you've made some changes to the template and that's what $compile is for.

I'm thinking this could be achieved with a decorator too, but I'll have to wait to have some more time to experiment with it.

Hope this helps.